# How do I case-insensitively check for equality?

Tags: python, if-statement, case-sensitive

When I use `if/else` I want the if to be case-insensitive. So instead of having to type `"What's Up"`, `"what's up"`, `"What's up"`, `"What's UP"`, et cetera, I can make it case insensitive and only use one variation of `"what's up"`.

Comment: Which language? Give an example. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Add tags related to the language and technology too.

Comment: 1 python 2ive tried to make all possible ways to word the if in this case what's up in caps @m02ph3u5

Comment: Make everything lower case or uppercase and compare or use a native case-insensitive function for camparison (if available).

Answer (score 2):

Convert the string to lower case (or upper case), and then compare:

```
>>> s = "What's Up"
>>> s.lower() == "What's up".lower()
True
```

Answer (score 0):

In any language, just make the text entered to be lowercase first and then compare it in the if/else block.

In java, you can store the value in a string and use the equalsIgnoreCase() method to compare values in if/else block.

Go to this link: [equalsIgnoreCase](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String))

Search for equalsIgnoreCase() method on this page

Check below link:

[case insensitive String comparison for Python](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String))

Hope this helps